# PostgreSQL full-text search for partial words

Tags: postgresql, optimization, indexing, full-text-search, query-optimization

When I use this query below, the search time is just around 60-100ms

```
SELECT *
FROM cmis.membership_masterfile 
WHERE textsearchable_index_col @@ to_tsquery ('ALO:*');
```

But when I use this query below, it goes up to 2000ms (with the same results from above)

```
SELECT *
FROM cmis.membership_masterfile 
WHERE textsearchable_index_col @@ utility.ts_query ('ALO');
```

The `utility.ts_query` is defined as:

```
-- Function: utility.ts_query(character varying)

-- DROP FUNCTION utility.ts_query(character varying);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION utility.ts_query(this_search_value character varying)
  RETURNS tsquery AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
        RETURN to_tsquery(
            'simple', 
            utility.format_search_value(this_search_value)
            );
        END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION utility.ts_query(character varying)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

And `utility.format_search_value(text)` is:

```
-- Function: utility.format_search_value(text)

-- DROP FUNCTION utility.format_search_value(text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION utility.format_search_value(this_search_value text)
   RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE 
        words text[];
        word text;
        formatted_text text = '';
        count int = 0;
        length int;
    BEGIN
        SELECT regexp_split_to_array(TRIM(this_search_value), E'\\s+' ) INTO words ;
        length = array_length(words, 1);

        FOREACH word IN ARRAY words
         LOOP
            count = count + 1;
            IF count = length THEN 
                formatted_text = formatted_text || word || ':*';
            ELSE
                formatted_text = formatted_text || word || ':*&';
            END IF;
         END LOOP; 

        RETURN formatted_text;  
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION utility.format_search_value(text)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Edit: `textsearchable_index_col` is defined as

```
ALTER TABLE cmis.membership_masterfile ADD COLUMN textsearchable_index_col tsvector;
UPDATE cmis.membership_masterfile SET textsearchable_index_col =  to_tsvector('simple', coalesce(membership_name) || ' '     ||coalesce(membership_no) || ' ' || coalesce(membership_id));
```

I think `utility.ts_query` does not use the index unlike `to_tsquery` which make use of the index. How should I make the `utility.ts_query` make use of the index or how should I make this faster without using `to_tsquery`?

EDIT: Query plan for 1st is

```
"Bitmap Heap Scan on membership_masterfile  (cost=24.23..134.64 rows=29     width=351)"
"  Recheck Cond: (textsearchable_index_col @@ to_tsquery('ALO:*'::text))"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on textsearch_idx  (cost=0.00..24.22 rows=29 width=0)"
"        Index Cond: (textsearchable_index_col @@ to_tsquery('ALO:*'::text))"
```

2nd query is

```
"Seq Scan on membership_masterfile  (cost=0.00..27597.94 rows=410 width=351)"
"  Filter: (textsearchable_index_col @@ utility.ts_query('ALO'::character varying))"
```

EDIT:

the result of `SELECT * FROM ts_debug('simple', utility.format_search_value('ALO'));` is 
`"asciiword";"Word, all ASCII";"ALO";"{simple}";"simple";"{alo}" "blank";"Space symbols";":*";"{}";"";""` 
and 
`SELECT * FROM ts_debug('ALO:*');` is 
`"asciiword";"Word, all ASCII";"ALO";"{english_stem}";"english_stem";"{alo}"
"blank";"Space symbols";":*";"{}";"";""`

Comment: what are execution plans of first query and query from utility.format_search_value('ALO')?..

Comment: It would be interesting to know the output of the following queries: `SELECT * FROM ts_debug('ALO:*');` and `SELECT * FROM ts_debug('simple', utility.format_search_value('ALO'));`. Also, how is `textsearch_idx` defined?

Comment: I used `CREATE INDEX textsearch_idx 
ON cmis.membership_masterfile
USING gin(textsearchable_index_col);`